# How to access inbox message in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, messaging, objective-c

I am developing an app in which there is a requirement under which I have open messages from 
inbox of iPhone in my app.

I can't seem to find any API through which I can do this - is there a way I can access inbox messages>

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this.

The only way you are able to excess email messages is by building the email access internal. You can only send message from within your own app.

Your app then sends that message to the email app on it's behalf and the mail app actually sends it, however does not interact with it beyond that point. For your app to be able to open messages from an inbox it would breach the security of the email account.